# Set form params in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test a create action where the user is authenticated via a remote API. Therefore, I do not have a user model. I have this in rspec:

```
describe "POST create" do 
  before { post :create, :user => {username: "john", password: "password"} }
  it { expect(response).to be_success }
end
```

This does not work. I looked at this rspec docs but could not find anything. How do I resolve this?

Comment: the post line should be in the it block

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a controller-spec, if you do like this it should work:

```
RSpec.describe UserControler, type: :controller do
  describe 'POST #create' do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      expect { 
        post :create, user: { username: 'john', password: 'password' }
      }.to change(User, :count).by(1)          
    end      
  end
end
```

To just check if the request is a success you can do:

```
it 'creates a new user' do  
  post :create, user: { username: 'john', password: 'password' }

  expect(response).to be_success
end
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The post line needs to be in the it block

```
describe "POST create" do 
  before { }
  it "returns 200 OK" do
    post :create, :user => {username: "john", password: "password"} 
    expect(response).to be_success
  end 
end
```